# Apache's ProxyPass and rewrite inside location

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I need to convert the following nginx configuration to apache:

```
location /api {
    rewrite  ^/api/(.*)$  /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://service.local:8989;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Rules above just take part of url after /api and proxy it to another server.
And I can't realize how it can be achieved in apache...
As far as I know it is not possible to define rewrite rules inside location in apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) you don't need the rewrite, the following will "forward" a request for `example.com/api/login?user=name` to `service.local:8989/login?user=name`

```
 ProxyPass /api http://service.local:8989/
 ProxyPassReverse /api http://service.local:8989/
 ProxyAddHeaders On
 ProxyPreserveHost On    # Typically not needed but keeps options the same as in question
```

Functionally the same as above but in a syntax more similar to nginx is to set the ProxyPass directive within a Location directive:

```
 <Location /api>
    ProxyPass http://service.local:8989/
    ProxyPassReverse http://service.local:8989/
    ProxyAddHeaders On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
 </Location>
```

Comment: To be precise, in this case in nginx you also don't need rewrite, but nobody reads documentation these days…

Comment: @Alexey, so can you please explain what is the right way to do proxying in this case?

Comment: @user144765 read documentation on `proxy_pass`